# Circuit design example

Tags: digital-logic

What will a combinational logic circuit look like using any basic gates having the output=1 when the input=110 and 101?

Comment: Hint: \$x \wedge (y \oplus z)\$

Comment: As for all questions that smell of homework: what have you done or found out so far, at what point are you stuck?

Comment: Hint: You can use a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to easily figure this out. Not sure if they still teach that or not.

Answer (score 2):

use 3 variable K-map for solving this problem

Comment: A Karnaugh map is only necessary for deriving the function  from raw inputs and outputs, or as an optimization tool for finding a minimal function. Here, the function is *already given* as a sum of products: the output is to be 1 if the inputs are 101 or 110 (and presumably 0 if the inputs are otherwise). From this you can go straight to gates (perhaps after some algebra). `xy'z + xy'z` -> `x(y'z + yz')`, and perhaps -> `x(y xor z)`.

Comment: already answer given by  Dilip Sarwate